# Discrete Math Proof; Find proof or counterexample

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

My intro to discrete math class homework is asking me to either prove or find a counterexample to the following statement:

For any integer $n \ge 3$, the number $n^2 − 1$ is composite.

I'm supposed to use basic ideas of number theory to help prove this. Any help or explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: First try some numerical examples and see why they are composite.  If you do not hit upon the right idea, look at the expression you have.  Can you recognize this as an algebraic expression from high school?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  can you factor $n^2-1$?

Answer (score 0):

If $n \geq 3$, then $n-1$ and $n+1$ are $> 1$, so $n^{2}-1 = (n-1)(n+1) > 1$. Every prime is by definition $\neq 1$ and can and only can be divided by $1$ and itself. But $n-1$ and $n+1$ divide $n^{2}-1$. Thus $n^{2}-1$ is composite by definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I am taking the composites as defined in terms of primes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Does your "detour" merits a "-1"? That is surprising... I do not assign a "-1" to any answer if it contains no unfixable error.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ... Can $n^{2}-1$ be a prime if $(n-1)$ and $(n+1)$ are $> 1$ and divide $n^{2}-1$?

Comment: You say that a prime can only be divided by $1$ and by itself. You said that $n-1$ and $n+1$ cannot be $1$. You forgot to say that they cannot be this "itself", i.e. $n^2-1$. In this detailed proof, you may not leave this unsaid.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Because they are key properties. Your reason is weird. Let me ask you something: Do you think we have to specify that the addition $+$ and the multiplication $\cdot $ are the usual ones? You are being unreasonable. But, you know what? Forget it. Random downvoters are abundant here.

Comment: The missing part of the argument is "$1<n-1,n+1<n^2-1$, hence $n^2-1$ has factors that witness its non-primality".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is true, but NOT "missing". What I was saying is that, something is left understood and need not say it again and again. The essential thing here is the notion of prime. Insisting on nonessential things is called pedantic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Alright. Then you are suggested to study more number theory... Way to go!